# embedded Word - Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am maintaining a software which uses WinWordControl from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to open word inside the application

It is now throwing an exception when adding an editor to the document

Line Code:

```
objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Editors.Add(ref editor);
```

Exception:
The requested member of the collection does not exist.

I am not sure what is wrong exactly or why it throws this exception as it used to work before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it used to work before" - before what? Before you changed something in your code, or before you upgraded something, such as an SDK or Word?

Comment: yeah u are right I have changed the version of office I used, I must have a problem with my environment as it did work on another PC. Thanks for pointing it up :)